# Getting data from Firebase with date range in Angular 2

Tags: angular, firebase

I have a Firebase collection like this:

[image]

I am trying to get the data that has the date range condition using this code:

**ticket-form.component.ts**

```
onSubmmitDates(value: any) {
    debugger;
    this.ts.getSpecificTicket(value.dateFrom, value.dateTo).subscribe((data: any) =>{
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

**ticket.service.ts**

```
private ticketList: AngularFireList<any>;

constructor(
    private firestore: AngularFirestore,
    private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase,
) { }
getSpecificTicket(dateFrom: Date, dateTo: Date): any {
    this.ticketList = this.afDatabase.list('tickets', ref =>
    ref.orderByChild('issuedOn').startAt(dateFrom.toString()).endAt(dateTo.toString()));
    return this.ticketList.snapshotChanges();
}
```

When I run it, I get this error:

> ERROR Error: permission_denied at /tickets: Client doesn't have
> permission to access the desired data.
> at errorForServerCode (index.cjs.js:642)
> at onComplete (index.cjs.js:8944)
> at Object.onComplete (index.cjs.js:12467)
> at index.cjs.js:11611
> at PersistentConnection.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_
> (index.cjs.js:11853)
> at Connection.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.Connection.onDataMessage_
> (index.cjs.js:11170)
> at Connection.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_
> (index.cjs.js:11164)
> at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (index.cjs.js:11065)
> at WebSocketConnection.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_
> (index.cjs.js:10657)
> at WebSocketConnection.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.WebSocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame
> (index.cjs.js:10707)

This is my rules:

[image]

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Have you set up firebase for your project properly? Take a look at this guide: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure You have given permissions to read/write as shown in the image.

[image]

Comment: Thannk you. It solved my problem but now i have a different one. It can't get the data from the database. I get 0 count.

Comment: Can you try getting all data from DB once and the by querying for specific data. Hope it will help you from getting out of your problem

Answer (score 1):

Check your permissions on your database Firebase. If you are on develope mode, you can just remove the permissions, but anyone will be able to access. For the time being when you are developing and you have not any problem with access permissions, You can simply do as shown below.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /{document=**} {
   allow read, write;
  }
 }
}
```

In the rules section.

Comment: Thannk you. It solved my problem but now i have a different one. It can't get the data from the database. I get 0 count.

Comment: I guess you are using the docs from the realtime database and you are using the firestore database. Instead of `list`, you have to use `collection`. Consider reading the docs for a better understanding.